# Third level keys often not working

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

My issue is very odd. The third level signs (with ALT GR) often don't work after using my PC a while. I can "fix" it, by logging out and in again into Windows. However, it is quite troublesome doing so often just to have every key available.

- They keyboard language is correct (DEU SG)
- My keyboard is the HP Premium USB Keyboard
- I'm using Windows 10
- The third level signs near the ENTER key always work: []{}
- Just the third level signs assigned on the number keys (0-9) don't work: @#¬|¢´~

What I did so far:

- I contacted Windows Support 3 times so far, they just checked everything (driver, settings, ...) but did obviously not fix anything

Any idea how to solve this misterious issue for good?

---

### Update

- Using a different USB port does not change anything.

Comment: Have you tried another keyboard to see if it a hardware or software issue?

Comment: When I use another keyboard and it works, it could still be both (hardware and software/driver), I assume? Although, if it would be the hardware, I guess it would never work instead of sometimes

Comment: see if it's helpful to you:https://helpdeskgeek.com/help-desk/how-to-fix-windows-keyboard-keys-which-stop-working/

Comment: @GloriaGu Thanks, what I will try is using a different USB port. However, quick fixes temporarily work already (logging out, restarting Windows), but I'm looking for a permanent solution here

Comment: @GloriaGu Using a different USB port doesn't change anything. Just logging out and in again does the "trick", but it's not a real solution